# Play YouTube Channel Videos using YouTube API in RecyclerView Android

Tags: java, android, video, android-recyclerview, youtube

I need to play YouTube channel videos in recyclerview. I am able to get all videoIds of the channel. The requirement is to show a single video as recyclerview item on full screen and on scroll up OR down, the next single video play, and so on. On recyclerview, only the first video plays successfully, on scroll down to display the next video the black screen appears, and no luck. I tried [this](https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/android-youtube-player/tree/master/core-sample-app/src/main/java/com/pierfrancescosoffritti/androidyoutubeplayer/core/sampleapp/examples/recyclerViewExample) android-youtube-player, and even extends the MainActivity from YouTubeBaseActivity but still no luck. Here is the code:

1. activity_main.xml

   ```
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/youtube_recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />
   ```
2. video_item

   ```
    <com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.core.player.views.YouTubePlayerView
        android:id="@+id/youTubePlayerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
   ```

3.YouTubeActivity code

```
    public class YouTubeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private String apiKey;
    private String playListID;
    private ArrayList<String> channelVideoIDs;
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_you_tube);

        playListID = getString(R.string.youtube_playlist_id);
        apiKey = getString(R.string.youtube_api_key);
        channelVideoIDs = new ArrayList<>();
        new GetPlayListVideosTask().execute();// This returns channel VideoIDs list
        initViews();
    }

    private void initViews(){

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_recyclerview);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(YouTubeActivity.this, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false));

        RecyclerViewAdapter recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(channelVideoIDs, this.getLifecycle());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
    }
}
```

4. RecyclerViewAdapter code

   public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

   ```
        private String[] videoIds;
        private ArrayList<String> videoIDList;
        private Lifecycle lifecycle;

        public RecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<String> videoIds, Lifecycle lifecycle) {

            this.videoIDList = videoIds;
            this.lifecycle = lifecycle;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_video_layout, parent, false);

            YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView)v.findViewById(R.id.youTubePlayerView);

            //YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_videos_container_youtube, parent, false);
            lifecycle.addObserver(youTubePlayerView);
            RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder vh = new RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder(youTubePlayerView);
            return vh;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

            viewHolder.loadVideo(videoIDList.get(position));
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {

            return videoIDList.size();
        }

        static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            private YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView;
            private YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer;
            private String currentVideoId;

            ViewHolder(YouTubePlayerView playerView) {

                super(playerView);
                youTubePlayerView = playerView;

                youTubePlayerView.addYouTubePlayerListener(new AbstractYouTubePlayerListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onReady(@NonNull YouTubePlayer initializedYouTubePlayer) {

                        Log.d("onReady", "ID: "+currentVideoId);

                        youTubePlayer = initializedYouTubePlayer;
                        youTubePlayer.loadVideo(currentVideoId, 0);
                    }
                });
            }

            void loadVideo(String videoId) {

                currentVideoId = videoId;
                if(youTubePlayer == null)
                    return;
                Log.d("loadVideo", "ID: "+currentVideoId);
                youTubePlayer.loadVideo(videoId, 0);
            }
        }
    }
   ```

Comment: What does `Log.d("loadVideo", "ID: "+currentVideoId);`do? it contains any data?- if so, add that info in your question.

Comment: @Marco Aurelio Fernandez Reyes, simply logging VideoId from the playlist.